# Change sort in SQLite

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

My dates are stored in this format:

```
3-1-2011
3-15-2011
```

However, it seems to be getting sorted like this:

```
3-1-2011
3-10-2011
...
3-19-2011
3-2-2011
3-20-2011
...
3-29-2011
3-3-2011
3-30-2011
```

So when I try to pull data using WHERE date BETWEEN 3-1-2011 AND 3-3-2011, it appears to return results for everything from 3-1 to 3-29. Without changing all the values, it it possible to fix this?

Comment: What datatype is the date field?

Comment: @Simon: SQLite doesn't employ strict data types like typical databases -- they think it's a "feature": http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data won't sort as DATEs because you aren't storing them as the SQLite supported format:

> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS

See the [data type documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the fact that SQLite doesn't assign any meaning to stored dates (they're simply text, real or integer columns, depending on the format you're using), I don't believe you can easily sort them in the manner you're storing them in. (That said, hopefully someone will prove me wrong.)

As such, two possible solutions would be:

1. **Store the dates as timestamps.** These would always sort correctly.
2. **Use the [date and time](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) functions to create a timestamp column on the fly.** You could create an alias using the date and time functions with the unixepoch modifier and sort based on this.

I unfortunately don't have access to sqlite at the moment to test these out at the moment, but I think they should be sound. (If not, someone will doubtless correct me.)

Answer (score 3):

SQLite does not have a "type" per column ([SQLite is typeless](http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html)).  These are equivalent

```
create table t(dt datetime)
create table t(dt int)
create table t(dt)
```

They all create a column dt that will be able to store any data.

The case statement below can be used to turn your `[m]m-[d]d-[yy]yy` data into a real date, which you can then update back to the table (to standardize) or use for sorting.

```
select dt, date(
case when dt like '%-%-__' then substr(dt,-2)
     when dt like '%-%-____' then substr(dt,-4) end
|| '-' ||
case when dt like '_-%' then '0' || substr(dt,1,1)
     when dt like '__-%' then substr(dt,1,2) end
|| '-' ||
case when dt like '__-_-%' then '0' || substr(dt,4,1)
      when dt like '__-__-%' then substr(dt,4,2)
      when dt like '_-_-%' then '0' || substr(dt,3,1)
      when dt like '_-__-%' then substr(dt,3,2) end)
from t
order by 2
```